# Does Zaryas alt fire increase in damage when you gain energy after firing?

Tags: overwatch

When I shoot Zaryas alt fire, then gain energy while that shot is still in the air, will that alt fire increase in damage as well or will it only be the same damage as is when I fired it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Zarya

> Every point of energy increases the damage of Particle Cannon.

And both the primary fire and the secondary fire are named "Particle Cannon". It's pretty safe to say that yes it does increase the damage.

<s>From there, I do **believe** that the damage should be calculated on impact. It would be a lot of data to transfer for each projectile individualy. This would reflect the behavior of McCree's ultimate when being buffed.</s>

---

### Short answer :

No. It won't amplify Zarya's damage.

---

Okay, after testing it (forgot to record it) the result is that Zarya's "grenade's" charge is recorded when fired. Meaning gaining charge after having fired it doesn't change the damage of the bullet. This was probably done to ensure that if the bullet is launched just before Zarya's death, that the damage stays higher than 0.

Please note that every other buffs works the other way around. Mercy buff and Ana's ult work on impact. If the target isn't boosted when the damage is done then the damage boost does not apply.

Comment: Fire a 0 charge shot directly at a target, look at the damage. Fire a second shot at the same target but healed up, with them shooting you after the projectile is in the air. Not too difficult to test, can be done with 2 people. I'm down for testing this later.

That said, given that every other damage source is boosted on application of the damage, I don't see why this will be any different

Comment: I could try to test it tonight (10 or so hours) if it's not done before. I'll provide video evidence too.

Comment: Just tested it. Honnestly I was surprised @KizTrap

Comment: I'll try to record it to bring something more to the answer.